# How can i divide ui elements width by two?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, calculator, divide

```
(float)rect.sizeDelta.x / 2.0f
```

I tried to divide rect transform's width by 2. but it only returns original value of rect transform's width. and size delta returns vector2 so i think both of them are float. so why is it happening and how can i solve this?

---edit----

this is my compelte code.

```
public move m;
    float oris;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        oris = transform.localScale.x;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (m.abletime - Time.time > 0)
        {
            transform.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(((m.killtime - (m.abletime - Time.time)) / m.killtime) * 100f, 100f);
        }
        var halfWidth = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width / 2f;
        GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(halfWidth, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Is your question how to divide it and re-assign the value? Because this should return half of the value but it won't do anything unless you assign it to something ... (Casting to `(float)` is redundant .. it already is one)

Comment: @derHugo no i just want to get half of value. i dont want to re-assign value.

Comment: Could you please post a complete reproducible example of your exact code? Have you tried to simply use `var halfWidth = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width / 2f;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`RectTransform.sizeDelta`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-sizeDelta.html) depends on your anchor settings and as the name suggests in most cases is a **delta** value

> If the anchors are in each of the four corners of the parent, the `sizeDelta` is how much bigger or smaller the rectangle is **compared to its parent.**

---

If you rather want the actual width you should probably rather use [`RectTransform.rect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html)

```
var halfWidth = GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width / 2f;
```